# Value input in Pentaho Spoon

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle

I am doing transformation using Spoon. I have an input table with this query:

```
select id, idOrder, date from TBL1 where date='2013-03-20';
```

I want to give an `idOrder` value manually from input. e.g. `idOrder = 405`

I see 'Get system info' but it has only dates.

How can I give variable input to the 'Table Input'?

Maybe I can say:

```
select ?, idOrder, date from TBL1 where date='2013-03-20';
```

But how can I provide a value for the `?` placeholder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Table+Input. You need to look at the information concerning replacing variables in your query/script. The syntax is pretty easy to use, like

```
select id, ${id_order_variable} as idOrder, date from TBL1 where date='2013-03-20'
```

Comment: Dont forget to tick the "replace variables" option! Causes many a confusion that does, not sure why it isnt the default!